# Switch Team Foundation Server account

Tags: authentication, tfs, visual-studio-2008

I am connecting to two different accounts on TFS online service with VS2008. For the past week, I have been experiencing an authentication issue when I try to switch between those two accounts.

When I open VS, it automatically connects to one of them (the last one I connected) and everything works fine. But if I choose to switch to another TFS account, I am prompted to log in and then the screen is redirected to the TFS Status web service.

I use the same login to connect to both accounts, I am the owner of these accounts and I can connect to both of these accounts with other versions of visual studio without a problem.

Any ideas?

[image]

Comment: Just try to add a windows credential for that account in Control Panel -> User Accounts -> User Accounts -> Manage your credentials.  If that not wok, just try to clean the VS caches and reset user data, then try it again.

Comment: clearing TFS cache (C:\Users\<user profile>\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Team Foundation\2.0\Cache\) allowed me to select an account to connect. But as soon as I select one, I cannot switch to another. I am requested to sign-in again and then redirected to the page above. Same behavior.

Comment: What's that mean for "`TFS account`" here? do you mean that you have two TFS servers or just connect to the same server with two different user accounts? You can try to run the VS with another user by command :`runas /netonly /user:<account> devenv.exe`, then check if that works. BTW, the TFS you used is too old, it's not supported any more by MS, it's time to consider migrating to the latest version now.

Comment: By TFS account I mean visual studio online subscription. Therefore I am switching team foundation servers. The login account is the same. I am using visual studio 2008 and I cannot migrate because certain types of projects were not supported in later versions. To overcome this problem, I sign out, close vs, re open it and connect to a different server. This doesn't explain however why this suddenly started to happen.

Comment: Generally the credentials will be remembered once you login, so have you tried to check the credentials in control panel - Manage your credentials? Are there any records related to the TFS in the credential manager?